# Create a stacked barplot with ggolot2 where percentages based on strings

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
mock_data <- data.table(person_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                        person_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        n = c(500, 607, 809, 120, 230, 12, 15, 80)
                       )
```

---

```
 person_1 person_2   n

       0    1       500
       0    2       607
       0    3       809
       0    4       120
       1    1       230
       1    2       12
       1    3       15
       1    4       80
```

For the `mock_data`, `n` represents the number of times where a combination of `person_1` and `person_2` exists. For example, the combination of `person_1 = 0` and `person_2 = 1` exists `n = 500` times.

I want to make a barplot where each bar shows the breakdown between `person_1` and `person_2`.

I tried a stacked barplot but as `0 + 1 = 1` not equal `500` i get an error.

Edit: 
What I would like to get
[image]

What I have at the moment

```
mock_data_2 <- mock_data %>%
+    mutate(person_combination = paste(person_1, person_2, sep = ", "))
```

---

```
ggplot(mock_data_2, aes(x=person_combination, y=n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, fill="tomato3")
```

[image]

Comment: Please show attempt, current graph output, and desired graph output (the latter may require some image app design).

Comment: @Parfait done!!!

Comment: Now I am confused. I did not see a stacked barplot or percentage calculation based on your updated example. Are you sure your title accurately depicted what you are looking for?

Comment: I too am confused. For `person_1 = 1` and `person_2 = 1`  you give `n = 230`; how do you split that into two stacked bars as in your picture? What are the values for `person_1` and `person_2`?

Comment: person_1 = 1 & person_2 = 1 happens 230 times. I want each bar to show the split between person_1 and person_2.

Comment: @Greconomist "*I want each bar to show the split between person_1 and person_2.*" What does that mean? Split how? How do you calculate the height for `person_1` and `person_2` from `n = 230`?

Comment: Basically, person_1 + person2 != 230. Imagine looking for instances where a garage offers a Tesla and a Ferrari for sale at the same time. Looking around the country we found 230 garages that were selling 1 Tesla and 1 Ferrari at the same time.

Comment: @Greconomist I didn't understand a word you just said. *How* do you calculate the `person_1` and `person_2` components, when you have `n = 230` for `person_1 = 1` and `person_2 = 1`? What is the equation? Do you divide 230 by 2 because you have two persons? What about `person_1 = 1` and `person_2 =  2`?

Comment: @Greconomist Please see my update to see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. We can calculate the percentage first using the `data.table` package and then plot it as a stacked barplot.

```
mock_data[, Percent := n/sum(n) * 100, by = person_1]

ggplot(mock_data, aes(x = factor(person_1), y = Percent, fill = factor(person_2))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "person_1") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "person_2") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**Update**

Here is an update based on OP's new information.

```
mock_data[, person_1_num := person_1/(person_1 + person_2) * n]
mock_data[, person_2_num := person_2/(person_1 + person_2) * n]
mock_data[, person_combination := paste(person_1, person_2, sep = "_")]
mock_data2 <- melt(mock_data, id.vars = c("person_combination"),
                   measure.vars = c("person_1_num", "person_2_num"))

ggplot(mock_data2, aes(x = person_combination, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]